# Unable to Insert node in Circular Singly linked list

Tags: python, algorithm, oop, data-structures, linked-list

I'm not able to get the desired output in the given code. The code is about **inserting nodes** in the **circular singly linked list**. Please correct this code as per the problems stated.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
 
class CircularSLL:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        
    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node
            if node.next == self.head:
                print('break')
                break
            node = node.next
            
    def insertnode(self, value, location):
        new_node = Node(value)
        
        # check if head is None or not
        
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
            new_node.next = self.head
            
        else:
            
            
            
            # At the start
            if location == 0:
                new_node.next = self.head
                self.head = new_node
                self.tail.next = self.head
            
            # At the end
            elif location == -1:
                new_node.next = self.tail.next
                self.tail.next = new_node
                self.tail = new_node
                
            else:
                
                # At specific location
                temp_node = self.head
                index = 0
                
                while index < location - 1:
                    
                    # node is the last element
                    if temp_node.next == self.head:
                        break
                    temp_node = temp_node.next
                    index += 1
                
                next_node = temp_node.next
                temp_node.next = new_node
                new_node.next = next_node
                
                if temp_node.next == self.head:
                    self.tail == temp_node
                    self.tail.next = self.head
                
            return 'The node has been successfully inserted'
 
cll = CircularSLL()
 
cll.insertnode(1,0)
 
cll.insertnode(3, 1)
 
cll.insertnode(4, 2)
 
cll.insertnode(5, 3)
 
cll.insertnode(6, 4)
 
print([node.value for node in call])
```

output = [1,3,4,5,6 ]

**1st problem - when inserting at index =  '0'.**

```
cll.insertnode(10,0)
```

output = [10,1]

**expected**

output = [10,1,3,4,5,6]

**2nd problem - when putting location = '-1'**

```
cll.insertnode(30, -1)
```

output = [1, 30]

**expected**

output = [10,1,3,4,5,6,30]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your test setup, `tail` is never getting set after the first node is inserted.

```
(Pdb) [c.value for c in cll]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
(Pdb) cll.head.value
1
(Pdb) cll.tail.value
1
(Pdb) cll.head is cll.tail
True
```

Your first problem is you have `self.tail == temp_node` instead of `self.tail = temp_node`, so let's fix that. Still, we're not getting the expected output:

`[1, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

The next problem is that by the time you check `if temp_node.next is self.head:`, you have already set `temp_node.next` to be `new_node`. It will never be `self.head`. I believe you intended to check `new_node.next` at this point, as it is now the last element.

Simply replace

```
                if temp_node.next == self.head:
                    self.tail == temp_node
                    self.tail.next = self.head
```

with

```
                if new_node.next is self.head:
                    self.tail = new_node
```

to get

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class CircularSLL:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node
            if node.next is self.head:
                break
            node = node.next

    def insertnode(self, value, location):
        new_node = Node(value)

        # check if head is None or not

        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
            new_node.next = self.head

        else:
            # At the start
            if location == 0:
                new_node.next = self.head
                self.head = new_node
                self.tail.next = self.head

            # At the end
            elif location == -1:
                new_node.next = self.tail.next
                self.tail.next = new_node
                self.tail = new_node

            else:
                # At specific location
                temp_node = self.head
                index = 0

                while index < location - 1:
                    # node is the last element
                    if temp_node.next is self.head:
                        break
                    temp_node = temp_node.next
                    index += 1

                next_node = temp_node.next
                new_node.next = next_node
                temp_node.next = new_node

                if new_node.next is self.head:
                    self.tail = new_node


            return 'The node has been successfully inserted'

cll = CircularSLL()

cll.insertnode(1,0)

cll.insertnode(3, 1)

cll.insertnode(4, 2)

cll.insertnode(5, 3)

cll.insertnode(6, 4)

cll.insertnode(10,0)

cll.insertnode(30, -1)

print([node.value for node in cll])
```

Output:
`[10, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 30]`

I have also replaced `==` with `is` in several places to more clearly test for identity rather than equivalent values.

Comment: Thanks..... you really saved my time... much appreciated it